# For SQL Server, how to fix simultaneous parallel table updates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have to update all records (add Guids) on two (indexed) empty columns of 150 tables, each table with around 50k records and exactly 4 existing columns.

On my local machine (16GB RAM, 500GB Samsung 850, SQL Server 2014, core i5) when I try to run 10 tables in parallel it takes a total of **13 minutes**, while if I run 5 the process finishes in mere **1.7 minutes**.

I do understand that something is busy on the disk level, but I need some help in how to quantify this huge difference in timings.

Is there a exact SQL Server DB view that I can check this discrepancy? Is there an exact way to figure out for a given hardware how many table updates can I run in parallel?? (the real test server has more RAM and 10k rpm disks).

Can anyone point to something that I can improve on the SQL Server to improve the timings for the running 10 tables in parallel?

I already tried increasing the Auto Growth size to 100MB from 10MB which improves the Disk Queue length (from around 5 to 0.1) but it does not actually decrease the total time that much.

**EDIT:**

Solution fond and its description:

Here is code which does the update:
[image]

Now the code has been changed to do 20k at a single time.

So basically previously it was running 10 (threads) X 40k update queries = 400k simultaneous update queries at the first run and then the rest 10 (threads) X 10k update queries, to update the all 50k records in those 10 different types.

And, now it does:

1. 10 (threads) X 20k update queries = 200k simultaneous update queries
2. 10 (threads) X 20k update queries = 200k simultaneous update queries
3. 10 (threads) X 10k update queries = 100k update queries

Result:
*Before: 13 minutes*,
*After: 1.8 minutes*

I am now checking to find out the best (fastest!) combination to update those 150 tables using multiple threads at the same time. Probably I can update a higher number of tables in parallel with a lower simultaneous update like 5k (from 20k) but I will be busy testing that now.

Comment: When you say "run 10 tables in parallel" do you mean something like 10 tabs in SSMS and execute them all at once, or similarly from a certain program that launches 10 at once?

Comment: Does it really matter? :)

I am running them from a c# console application.
I create an update script of 40k update statements, separated by semi-colon, and run them at once in every thread.

Comment: Context always matters.

Comment: In any case, I would write this out in one long script and run it that way. Either from SSMS or from your program, doesn't matter. SQL Server will then run it as well as it can.

Comment: Indeed, that's is what I am doing also..... :)

Comment: Probably quicker to perform a bulk insert into temp table (s)  then update your target tables from them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been [reposted on DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126637/for-sql-server-how-to-fix-simultaneous-parallel-table-updates) and answered there. [Please do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @Gilles I agree, I shall close this question now. I cannot do it today but shall do it tomorrow.

Comment: You should be looking for bulk updates, now that I'm seeing the actual statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. :)

Instead of running the 40K update queries at once (I create an update script of 40k update statements as stated in the comment above) if I decrease the that number to half of it - 20k update queries at once there is a huge improvement - 10 tables in parallel it takes a total of 1.3 minutes now - I can now continue. 
Thanks for your inputs and help so far.

Comment: I am intrigued to see a snippet of this update script with 40k or 20k update queries. Are you able to update your answer (or question) to show what this script looks like?

Comment: @philosophicles yes, sure. I am planning to do that now. I was busy testing it to find the "sweet spot" (or number) for the batch size.

Comment: @philosophicles I have added the details now.